# Area of a circle from equation for circle

Tags: circles

Q. Equation of circle- $2x^2+ \lambda xy+2y^2+( \lambda -4)x+6y-5=0$ find area of the circle.

Attempt-
For converting the equation from second degree to first degree $\lambda xy=0$.

Thus, $\lambda =0$ and-

$$(\lambda -4)x = 2gx$$
$$ 6y=2fy$$
$$c=-5$$
$$g=-2, f=3, c=-5$$

Radius of circle = $\sqrt{4+9+5}=\sqrt{18}$

Area of circle= $ \pi *18$

But the answer is $\frac {23}{4} * \pi$

Comment: Your argument would be correct if the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ were $1$. But they are not.

Comment: Do they need to be equal? Correct me but shouldn't just their coefficient be equal? To satisfy $a=b$ where a and b are coefficients of x and y respectively

Comment: @AkshatBatra Yes, the coefficients of the quadratic expressions for $\;x\,,\,\,y\;$ must be equal if we have a circle (otherwise it is an ellipse), **but then** you *must*  divide through the whole equation by that common coefficient, and that affects the radius...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete squares after putting $\;\lambda xy=0\implies \lambda =0\;$:

$$0=2x^2+2y^2-4x+6y-5=2(x-1)^2-2+2\left(y-\frac32\right)^2-\frac92-5\implies$$

$$\implies2(x-1)^2+2\left(y-\frac32\right)^2=\frac{23}2\implies(x-1)^2+\left(y-\frac32\right)^2=\frac{23}4$$

and we have a circle of radius $\;\sqrt{\frac{23}4}\;$ , so its area is

$$\pi\sqrt{\frac{23}4}^2=\frac{23\pi}4$$